# Use of OS_creat in cFS

Tags: c, core-flight-system

It seems that I am not able to create files with OS_creat. I always receive this:

EVS Port1 66/1/TFTP_APP 134: DecodeRequestString(): /tmp/dest.txt, octet EVS Port1 66/1/TFTP_APP 139: TFTP error opening WRQ file /tmp/dest.txt Status = -108

I have tried using OS_creat from other apps but it seems that it does never work for me.

Do you know some typical issues about this that could be the problem?.

Comment: How are you calling OS_creat? What does OS_creat return? Is `-108` an errno code, is it anyhow relevant? What "other apps" are using OS_creat? How "other apps" are calling OS_creat? What is the source of your program? What is the source of "other apps"? Can you create an MCVE? Is the `/tmp/dest.txt` file anyhow relevant? How are you receiving "this" error? message? From where? is the `"TFTP_APP" any relevant? What are you trying to do? What is the expected behavior you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OS_creat()` call is actually implemented in the OSAL.  The value -108 that you see refers to an OSAL error code, which can be found in the file `osapi-os-filesys.h` as:

```
#define OS_FS_ERR_PATH_INVALID         (-108)
```

It is important to understand that OSAL does not directly use the underlying OS filesystem, but rather uses a system of "virtual mount points".

Every file-related operation such as opening or creating a file will get translated from a virtual file name (e.g. the name you supplied, `/tmp/dest.txt`) to an actual filename in the underlying system.  It is implemented this way because some RTOS's have different ways of specifying filenames, particularly if the reside on separate block devices and some RTOS's do not have the concept of a UNIX-like unified virtual file system.

This translation is implemented by the `OS_TranslatePath()` function which in turn references the system volume table, `OS_VolumeTable`, which is typically defined by the platform support package you are using.  If this translation fails, it returns `OS_ERR_PATH_INVALID` (-108).

The system volume table has several fields, such as:

```
{"/eedev0",  "./cf",      FS_BASED,        FALSE,     FALSE,    TRUE,     "CF",      "/cf",     512   },
```

The source file should have a more complete key as to what all the fields mean, but important to note that on POSIX deployments only `FS_BASED` modes are really supported, which is a map to the underlying filesystem.  For this mode the `PhysDev` (2nd parameter) actually refers to the existing path in the underlying filesystem (not a physical device).

To solve your issue, you need to do one of:

- Add a mapping for `/tmp` to your OS_VolumeTable in your PSP, to map it to the underlying file system.
- Use a path that already has a mapping, such as `/cf` in the example above.

Hope this helps!